# how to turn a tuple to a string and back in python / how to edit an associative array on a web page

Tags: python

**The problem I'm really trying to solve:**

I have a square table of true/false values, with rows and columns labelled by strings.

I want to display this as an html form with checkboxes, allow the user to tick and untick elements, then submit the form, and then I want to reconstruct the array from the form.

**The subproblem I'm trying to solve at the minute:**

I have a tuple of two strings, ("foo", "bar")

I want to turn that into the name of a checkbox in a webpage

And then when the form is submitted, turn that string back into the original tuple.

At the moment I'm doing, ("%s$%s" % ("foo", "bar"))-> "foo$bar" and then string.split('$') to get the strings back, which works fine but it's hackish and will break if the strings ever have dollars in them.

Obviously I can't just use repr and eval!

Is there a sane, standard way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like json is the usual way, and it's a python built-in

> > > import json
> > >
> > > json.dumps(("hi","there"))
> > >       '["hi", "there"]'
> > >
> > > json.loads('["hi", "there"]')
> > >       [u'hi', u'there']
> > >
> > > json.loads(json.dumps(("hi","th'ere",'the"e$re')))
> > >       [u'hi', u"th'ere", u'the"e$re']

Answer (score 1):

Your second problem is impossible without remembering a state on the server. The client must and shall always be seen as **unsafe**. There is **no** sane way of getting the same strings back as you sent. The user can always hack in on some way.

Unless you want to do this cryptographically, which I really doubt :)

However, if you're not worried about script kiddos breaking your app there are thousands of ways, for example what you did, but also saving in a hidden field the length of the first string, which leaves the rest of the string for the second string. Or saving the strings in two different fields, etc.

Comment: Hi, yes, I was wondering if there was a 'usual' way. Looks like it's json.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just nest structures? Given the need for a matrix of values and descriptions, why not nest them like this:

```
matrix = [
     [{'value': False, 'string':'str1'}, {'value': False, 'string':'str2'}],
     [{'value': False, 'string':'str1'}, {'value': False, 'string':'str2'}],
     ]
```

Now `matrix[0][0]` represents a dictionary with keys `string` and `value`. Without too much of a headache you can convert this to a html table.

Now, you could also (assuming you don't need modification) use nested tuples.

The hard part is reconstruction. You'll need to form the `name` tags carefully; I'd suggest from the indices you're using to navigate the matrix like so:

```
print "<table>"
for i in range(0, 2):
    print "<tr>"
    for j in range(0, 2):
        print "<td>"
        item = '<input name="matrix-%d-%d" value=%s>%s<br/>' % (i,j,
                 str(matrix[i][j]["value"]), matrix[i][j]["string"])
        print item
        print "</td">
    print "</tr>"
print "</table>"
```

The task then remaining to you is to recreate said list from the post values, which is basically a case of splitting the string, working out if the bounds are sensible (expected?) and populating the dictionary values.

Comment: cool, thanks, my solution looks a bit like this, it's the string parsing that I'm worrying about.